# Streamlit / Pandas query / filtering for existing values and ignoring not existing

Tags: python, pandas, streamlit

I can imagine this question has been asked a lot, but I can´t find a needed approach:

I built a dashboard in streamlit and everything works fine. I want to show data based on some filters:

```
Date = st.sidebar.multiselect(
    "Please select the month:",
    options=df["Date"].unique(),
    default=month
    )
Type = st.sidebar.multiselect(
    "Please select the type:",
    options=df["Type"].unique(),
    default=df["Type"].unique()
    )

df_selection = df.query(
    "Date == @Date & Type == @Type"
)
```

In column "Type" there are only three types: "A", "B", "C". Some months have only types "A" and "B" and some all three.

If I select the months with only "A" and "B" streamlit throws an error: `KeyError: 'C'` and

```
File "app.py", line 106, in <module>
    c = typen.loc["C"]
```

I avoided it with:

```
if 'C' in types.index:
    c = types.loc["C"]
else:
    c = 0
a = types.loc["A"]
b = types.loc["B"]
```

I tried to do it for other types ("A" and "B") but it does not really work. Maybe I need a combination of `for loop` and `try & catch` to make `multiselect` more flexible.

So basically I need a way to scan my `DataFrame` for missing data based on filters, ignore them or replace with 0 and return the existing ones.

But somehow I can´t come further and need an advice :)

Comment: Could you post a minimal reproducible code?

Comment: I could solve it with a chain of if´s and try and except. Basically what I wrote in the last part of question.